# Flutter bloc saves data and not updating

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit

I am making an app that displays work projects with images,text,
using Cubit with Clean Architecture, i get data and display them successfully, but when i close the app and open it again it show only the same data shown in last session.
tried opening the app offline it also shows the data even with no internet connection.
i have multiple blocs, cubit in my app and all of them seems to be saving their state and data even after closing the app.

Iam using GetIt to handle getting bloc instance. and using MultiBloc provider on top of Main.dart
tried using resetState method by invoking emit(WhateverStateInitial());
yet same problem.

any solution why data and state seems to be saved?

Comment: Are you disposing all the cubit and bloc instances your taking through out the application, that may causing the problem.

Comment: Iam using GetIt, So i don't manually Dispose anything

Comment: Without any code it's hard to tell where the issue is. Can you poste a minimal example of your problem?

Comment: can i use this inside ondispose: 
    BlocProvider.of<PublicProductsCubit>(context).close();

???

Answer (score 0):

Without code it is hard to understand, but it seems like you cubit/bloc is created somewhere on global level and it lifetime is equal to lifetime of aplication lifetime. if application is killed by system or by user, and you don't persists data, so data will be gone with cubit/bloc disposing.

second moment is how you fetch you data in cubit/bloc. in this way data will refetch every time widget is created:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      BlocProvider.of<SomeScreenCubit>(context).fetchData();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Iam using GetIt to handle getting bloc instance. and using MultiBloc provider on top of Main.dart

Comment: This is exactly what I assumed in my answer - the lifetime of a qubit is equal to the lifetime of an application. if the application has not been killed, then the qubit takes the data that is already there.
what about the data load call?

Comment: iam using clean architecture so having a remote data source with all function which get's invoked with cubit function.
then using state to get data from.

Comment: you didn't answered to the questoin: how and when do you call method from cubit to fetch data?

Comment: in widget initstate i call Bloc.of<Cubit>(context).function, after than i use blocbuilder and check fo rstate to get it's data